# Google Picker API not firing callback when using toUri() in iframe

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-picker

I'm trying to get the Google Picker API to work inside an iframe instead of the default modal that loads on top of everything. I get the picker to load, can browse files, but when I click 'Select' the callback never fires.

If I use the modal version instead of the `toUri` the callback fires as expected.

My code (mostly copied and pasted from their demo)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Picker API Quickstart</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <p>Picker API API Quickstart</p>

  <!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
  <button id="authorize_button" onclick="handleAuthClick()">Authorize</button>
  <button id="signout_button" onclick="handleSignoutClick()">Sign Out</button>

  <pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>
  <iframe id="pickerFrame" style="display: none;width:500px;height:500px"></iframe>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /* exported gapiLoaded */
    /* exported gisLoaded */
    /* exported handleAuthClick */
    /* exported handleSignoutClick */

    // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
    // included, separated by spaces.
    const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file';

    // TODO(developer): Set to client ID and API key from the Developer Console
    const CLIENT_ID = '******';
    const API_KEY = '******';
    // TODO(developer): Replace with your own project number from console.developers.google.com.
    const APP_ID = '******';

    let tokenClient;
    let accessToken = null;
    let pickerInited = false;
    let gisInited = false;


    document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';

    /**
     * Callback after api.js is loaded.
     */
    function gapiLoaded() {
      gapi.load('client:picker', initializePicker);
    }

    /**
     * Callback after the API client is loaded. Loads the
     * discovery doc to initialize the API.
     */
    async function initializePicker() {
      await gapi.client.load('https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest');
      pickerInited = true;
      maybeEnableButtons();
    }

    /**
     * Callback after Google Identity Services are loaded.
     */
    function gisLoaded() {
      tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES,
        callback: '', // defined later
      });
      gisInited = true;
      maybeEnableButtons();
    }

    /**
     * Enables user interaction after all libraries are loaded.
     */
    function maybeEnableButtons() {
      if (pickerInited && gisInited) {
        document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
      }
    }

    /**
     *  Sign in the user upon button click.
     */
    function handleAuthClick() {
      tokenClient.callback = async (response) => {
        if (response.error !== undefined) {
          throw (response);
        }
        accessToken = response.access_token;
        document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Refresh';
        await createPicker();
      };

      if (accessToken === null) {
        // Prompt the user to select a Google Account and ask for consent to share their data
        // when establishing a new session.
        tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: 'consent' });
      } else {
        // Skip display of account chooser and consent dialog for an existing session.
        tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: '' });
      }
    }

    /**
     *  Sign out the user upon button click.
     */
    function handleSignoutClick() {
      if (accessToken) {
        accessToken = null;
        google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(accessToken);
        document.getElementById('content').innerText = '';
        document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Authorize';
        document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }
    }

    /**
     *  Create and render a Picker object for searching images.
     */
    function createPicker() {
      const view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
      view.setMimeTypes('image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg');
      const picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
        .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
        .setAppId(APP_ID)
        .setDeveloperKey(API_KEY)
        .setOAuthToken(accessToken)
        .addView(view)
        .setCallback(pickerCallback);
      picker.build();

      document.getElementById('pickerFrame').src = picker.toUri();
      document.getElementById('pickerFrame').style.display = 'block';
      //picker.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Displays the file details of the user's selection.
     * @param {object} data - Containers the user selection from the picker
     */
    async function pickerCallback(data) {
      if (data.action === google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        let text = `Picker response: \n${JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}\n`;
        const document = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
        const fileId = document[google.picker.Document.ID];
        console.log(fileId);
        const res = await gapi.client.drive.files.get({
          'fileId': fileId,
          'fields': '*',
        });
        text += `Drive API response for first document: \n${JSON.stringify(res.result, null, 2)}\n`;
        window.document.getElementById('content').innerText = text;
      }
    }
  </script>
  <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoaded()"></script>
  <script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisLoaded()"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I've tried adding console logs and breaks to the callback but it just never fires when loading in the iframe with `toUri()`.

Comment: I just tried the Google Picker API and I was able to return the `fileId` right after I clicked the select button. Make sure that you enable the Drive API in Google Cloud console and see if that works.

Comment: The code above works if you uncomment the ‘setVisible()’ line and comment out the line that sets the iframe source. Running it as is without the popup and using the embedded iframe it never fires the callback.